# .NET String.Format Include Minus Sign in Count for Padding 0

Tags: .net, string.format

I'm porting some C++ code which is using _vsnwprintf_s to convert numbers to 11 character strings. If the number is negative it still returns 11 character string.

I need to replicate this behavior in C#. If I use:

```
String.Format("{0:D11}",-30800322);
String.Format("{0:D11}",30800322);
```

The problem is the negative number results in 12 character output, not 11. i.e. it outputs -00030800322 but I want it to output -0030800322 while 30800322 should output 00030800322.

I can resolve it by checking if the number is negative and using `{0:D10}` for negative numbers and `{0:D11}` for positive numbers, however I'm wondering if there is a better way to more closely replicate the C++ version which includes the minus sign in the count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many ways to get that output. So you have two variables for a positive and negative values:

```cs
var s = -30800322;
var u = 30800322;
```

> **1. string.Replace**

---

The quick-and-easy way:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:D11}", s).Replace("-0", "-"));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:D11}", u).Replace("-0", "-"));
```

> **2. IFormatProvider**

---

Create a custom [IFormatProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformatprovider?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) to use it with the `string.Format(..)` function:

```cs
public class vsnwprintf : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
    public string Format(string format, object arg, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
    {
        if (arg == null || !int.TryParse(arg.ToString(), out int x))
            return null;

        var f = "{0:D11}";

        if (x < 0)
            return string.Concat("-", string.Format(f, x).Substring(2));
        else
            return string.Format(f, x);
    }

    public object GetFormat(Type formatType)
    {
        return (formatType == typeof(ICustomFormatter)) ? this : null;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(new vsnwprintf(), "{0}", s));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(new vsnwprintf(), "{0}", u));
```

> **3. ToString()**

---

Create a new class and override the `ToString()` function:

```cs
public class vsnwprintf
{
    private readonly int Value;
    private readonly int Length;

    private vsnwprintf() { }

    public vsnwprintf(int val, int length) : this()
    {
        Value = val;
        Length = length;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var f = string.Concat("{0:D", Length, "}");

        if (Value < 0)
            return string.Concat("-", string.Format(f, Value).Substring(2));
        else
            return string.Format(f, Value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(new vsnwprintf(s, 11));
Console.WriteLine(new vsnwprintf(u, 11));
```

> **4. Extension Method**

---

Create a static class and create an extension method for the `int` type:

```cs
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string Tovsnwprintf(this int Value, int Length = 11)
    {
        var f = string.Concat("{0:D", Length, "}");

        if (Value < 0)
            return string.Concat("-", string.Format(f, Value).Substring(2));
        else
            return string.Format(f, Value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(s.Tovsnwprintf());
Console.WriteLine(u.Tovsnwprintf(11));
```

Each of which returns:

```
-0030800322
00030800322
```